# Show timestamp on JQGrid ReloadGrid

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I am using a JQgrid with MVC4. I am reloading the grid data every 10 seconds with this:

```
setInterval(function () { jQuery("#JQGrid1").trigger("reloadGrid"); }, 10000);
```

What I would like to do is have on my page a timestamp that updates whenever the grid reloads. Right now I am using:

```
<h2>Events as of @ViewBag.Time</h2>
```

but obviously this only gets set when the page first loads. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I will try these out Monday and select an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just create an element on the page and update that on the reload.

```
<div id="timestampDiv"></div>

setInterval(function () { 
     var timestampvalue = Date().toString();//format timestamp however you like here.
     jQuery("#JQGrid1").trigger("reloadGrid"); 
     jQuery('#timestampDiv').text(timestampvalue);
}, 10000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Could do something like this:

```
setInterval(function () { 
    jQuery("#JQGrid1").trigger("reloadGrid");
    $('#timestamp').text(Date().toString());
}, 10000);
```

Comment: Thank you. Chose other answer for being more complete. Yours is correct as well though.